# Random numbers in variable without repeating

Tags: php

I am trying this little code but in '$person1' and in '$person2' the same random numbers are shown.

Is it possible to show different random numbers on each call to the variable '$randomNumbers'?

```
$randomNumbers = rand(0,10);

$person1= [
    'note' => [$randomNumbers]
];

$person2= [
    'note' => [$randomNumbers]
];

$data=[$person1,$person2];
```

Comment: You are only generating one random number.

Comment: just insert `rand(0,10)` into your `$person1` and `$person2`, like so: `$person1= ['note' => [rand(0,10)]];` `$person2= ['note' => [rand(0,10)]];`. That does not mean that, at times, you cannot have identical random numbers for both.

Answer (score 2):

generate another random number before assigning it. This does not ensure that both numbers are always different!

```
$randomNumber = rand(0,10);

$person1= [
    'note' => [$randomNumber]
];

$randomNumber = rand(0,10);

$person2= [
    'note' => [$randomNumber]
];

$data=[$person1,$person2];
```

I want to note, that having duplicate code like this is a bad practice. you probably want to move the duplicate code into a function that returns a person.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function and an array to store the random generated numbers to avoid duplication. Try -

```
<?php

function random_no($numbers)
{
    $rand = rand(0, 10);// Generate number
    if (!in_array($rand, $numbers)) { // check if already exists in previously generated numbers
        return $rand;
    } else { // generate again and check for unique number
        random_no($numbers);
    }
}
$numbers = [];
$numbers[] = $rand = random_no($numbers);

$person1= [
    'note' => [$rand]
];

$numbers[] = $rand = random_no($numbers);

$person2= [
    'note' => [$rand]
];

$numbers[] = $rand = random_no($numbers);

$person3= [
    'note' => [$rand]
];

$data=[$person1,$person2,$person3];
print_r($data);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/1077395)